# Why we consider excitations only near the Fermi surface?

Tags: solid-state-physics

In a metallic system, one typically consider states only near the Fermi surface. When we consider thermal excitation, I can understand this "approximation", because the Fermi-Dirac statistics implies that if we go away from the Fermi surface, then the probability of occupation (or one minus probability of occupation) decays exponentially. However, is it still valid when we consider excitation by purturbation?
Consider a general one-particle purturbing Hamiltonian
$$ H'= \sum_{\mathbf k, \mathbf k'} V_{\mathbf k \mathbf k'} c^\dagger_{\mathbf k} c_{\mathbf k'}.$$
In this case, the transition rate from $\mathbf k$ to $\mathbf k'$ is proportional to $|V_{\mathbf k \mathbf k'}|^2$, by Fermi's golden rule. I have seen in some literature that one still approximates by considering only $\mathbf k$ and $\mathbf k'$ near the Fermi surface. However, large transition rate may be possible for $\mathbf k, \mathbf k'$ not near the Fermi surface for suitable $|V_{\mathbf k \mathbf k'}|^2$. In this case the near-the-Fermi-surface approximation still valid?

Comment: Even if the transition rate might be large, any state more than a few $kT$ from the Fermi surface won't be occupied so doesn't matter how big the transition rate is.

Comment: @JonCuster Could you elaborate more on this? Why state more than a few kT from the Fermi surface won't be occupied?

Comment: The matrix elements for the transition might be large but that is weighted by the probability of occupancy of the state. If that is tiny the transition rate will be tiny too.

Comment: @boyfarrell Actually I also considered that point. However, the transition rate from $\mathbf k$ to $\mathbf k'$ is proportional to $|V_{\mathbf k \mathbf k'}|^2 n_F(\mathbf k) (1-n_F(\mathbf k'))$. The second factor is related to the probability of ocupancy. If $\mathbf k$ is much smaller than $k_F$ and $\mathbf k'$ is much larger than $k_F$, then $n_F(\mathbf k) (1-n_F(\mathbf k'))$ will be very close to 1.